# transfer rows to columns in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rows, transpose

I'm already struggling for two days just to transfer a selection of rows to a new column in r.
My dataset looks like this:
My starting point is "big_data". This is the data I have in a dataframe. The output should be "blub" in a dataframe. In blub the cdolumns should have names representing the value of i.
[image: data mutatie]

Finally I came up with:

[image: code]
I tried so many things already, but he doesn't want to give me the output as in the picture above.
Is there someone who can help me whit this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)
Additionally, it would be easier to answer, when you would provide the data as a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider`, from the `tidyr` package. For example:

```r
library(tidyr)

blub <- pivot_wider(
  data = big_data,
  id_cols = id,
  names_from = i,
  values_from = Outstanding_LCY,
  names_glue = "kolom{.value}"
)
```

Comment: Dear Tobi, you are the best! This is exactly were I was looking for.  Thank you so much!
After running your code I added "blub<-data.frame(blub)" to make it again a dataframe, but he named the columns as X1, X2, X3 en X4. Since i is not always 4, is there a way to rename these dynamically in e.g. kolom1, kolom2.... kolomk?